# Solr always returns 10 rows

Tags: java, solr

```
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.setQuery("num:[20 TO 30]&fl=num&rows=50&start=10&sort=num desc");
QueryResponse rsp;
rsp = server.query(query);
SolrDocumentList returned = rsp.getResults();
System.out.println(returned.size());
```

Why do I always get 10 documents?? (when I try this through GET in a web browser I get what I want)

EDIT
I actually found out that  it works when the query is created this way:

```
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery().setQuery(
            "num:[20 TO 30]").setSortField("num", ORDER.desc).setRows(5);
```

Comment: I'm no Solr expert but maybe `num:[20 TO 30]` is not interpreted by the browser but by `SolrQuery` and this tells the query to return entries 20 to 29 (assuming the end point is exclusive).

Comment: no, it means that num field has to be within those bounds. Has nothing to do with how many rows are in the result

Answer (score 3):

You can change the behavouir of the `requestHandler`. By default it returns 10 rows. Change the setting of `rows` in `defaults` to another value.

```
<requestHandler name="..." class="...">

 <lst name="defaults">
   <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
   <int name="rows">10</int>
   <str name="df">text</str>
 </lst>

</requestHandler>
```

On client side the param you are looking for is `rows` : `...&start=0&rows=10...`

**EDIT**

You are using solrj as client as I assume. The implementation of `setQuery`

```
public SolrQuery setQuery(String query) {
    this.set(CommonParams.Q, query); // whereas CommonParam.Q is 'q'
    return this;
}
```

This means you have to call explicit `setRows` and cannot use the params as in a URL.